# What is the correct way to use Html.Editor() helper with objects of type known only at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm in this situation:

I have a controller that initializes a view with a model that has a property of type DbSet (generic):

```
private DbContext db = new DbContext ();
Model.Entities = db.Set (t.GetType ());
Model.Entities.Load();
return View (model);
```

Now in the view I would like to cycle entity properties in this way:

```
foreach (var item in Model.Entities)
{
     foreach (var columnName in Model.Columns){
          @ Html.Editor ("item."+columnName)
     }
}
```

But I just get a empty textbox.

What is the correct method to do this?

**My purpose:**
My aim is to create a controller that creates all that is needed for CRUD operations by varying the table name from querystring (similar to Dynamic Data) instead of creating individual controllers / views for each table (model)

**edit**
I understand the problem: html.editor uses reflection to find the property in Model. 
No way to change the context?

Comment: What's the purpose of loading a generic set but then trying to get a non-generic property for each item in it?

Comment: You are way way waaaaay overdoing the generic thing friend.

Comment: The purpose is to create something like dynamic data

Comment: `I would like to cycle entity properties in this way` why do you *need* to do that.  MVC has a Editor Template for [object that will automagically loop through all the properties and create editors for them based on type/attributes (and available since version 2.0)](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html).  Simply use [EditForModel()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorformodel(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: Thank you Erik, nice tutorial!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, use a PartialView to change the context of the helper, the code then becomes:

```
foreach (var item in Model.Entities)
{
     @Html.Partial ("_Rows", item)
}
```

and in the PartialView:

```
foreach (string column in ((TEntity)Model).ScaffoldColumns)
{
    @Html.Editor(column)
}
```